# How to "unload" a .properties file

Tags: java, file, io

in my game i'm loading properties files from a specific level folder with this code:

```
Properties prop = new Properties

public void LoadLevel(int levelID) {
try {
   prop.load(new FileInputStream("/resources/levels" + levelID + "lev.properties"));
....snip....
```

if I want to load another level, how do I unload the last level's properties file?
I found a solution, but it was blurred as the site was pay only, so I came crawling back here :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Properties` is a `Hashtable`. You can [`clear`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html#clear%28%29) it.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to just create a new `Properties` object, load it, and assign it to `prop`.  This should work just fine, unless your code has saved the reference to the original object in other places.

Comment: so when you `prop.load();` another file it erases the old table? or does it pile up with multiple properties files?

Comment: @Young_Maker - if you create a new Properties object, that is irrelevant.  But the javadoc doesn't mention that `load` erases the previous entries, so I don't imagine that it does.

Comment: oh, I see what your saying. But I wanted a way to keep the current Properties object and load a new file into it